# $x_1$ is irreducible in $K[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]/\langle x_1x_4-x_2x_3\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Goal: $x_1$ is irreducible in $K[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]/\langle x_1x_4-x_2x_3\rangle$ where $K$ is a field.

My attempt so far:

Let $a,b\in R/\langle x_1\rangle$, $[a],[b]\neq[0]$.  Then $a=p_ax_1^{k_a}+q_a$ and $b=p_bx_1^{k_b}+q_b$ where $k_a,k_b\in K$, $p_a,p_b\in K[x_2,x_3,x_4]$.  We have $ab=p_ap_bx^{k_a+k_b}+p_aq_bx_1^{k_a}+p_bq_ax_1^{k_b}+q_aq_b$.  Since $q_aq_b\in K[x_2,x_3,x_4]$, $[ab]\neq[0]$.

Is this correct?

Comment: $x_1$ is not prime and it seems to me that in you are trying to prove that $x_1$ is prime in your question.

Comment: Doh!  Updated.  Why is $x_1$ not prime?

Comment: When we make the quotient by $x_1$ we get $K[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]/(x_2 x_3)$ which is not a domain.